# Azure function response in Power apps returns true/false instead of value

Tags: azure-functions, powerapps

I am trying to integrate an Azure function from PowerApps.
The function returns a very simple JSON:

{
  "response": "test"
}

Testing the custom connector from PowerApps works fine and returns the right result however when I use this connector inside the app itself it returns true/false rather than the value of the response.

All the forums/blogs I've found say to define the variable on the button as follows-
UpdateContext({testvar:'functioname'.FunctionPOST("test")})

Then use testvar to show the response but all I get is true/false rather than the response. 
Looking at the variables confirms that the variable gets created as Boolean (and if I try to create it as a string typed global variable it gets converted to a Boolean typed Screen variable).
I checked the response definition on the custom connector and it is set correctly to 'string'.
Ideas?

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "testing the custom connector from PowerApps works fine" vs "use this connector inside the app itself"?

Comment: When I use the Test tab in the Custom Connector wizard I get the expected response JSON :
 {
"result": "success"
}
When I make a call to the connector from within the app itself the collection is populated with the correct header ("result") but there are no values (expected "success").
Hope it makes sense.

Comment: Did you solve this? I'm trying to get my web API via custom connector to return JSON results to Power Apps, but all I get is a true/false?

Comment: same happened with me

Answer (score 0):

I know that the previous messages are old. But like a newbie in Azure Functions and Powerapps I've walked around the same problem of the boolean response in spite of the execution of testing connector works fine.
After 'some' hours dedicated I solved the problem putting explicitly the default response as string in the connector. I put this message in order to save time to newbies as me ;-)
[definitionresponsedefaultstring](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WZXgW.png)
[swaggerconnector](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zIU7u.png)